# Why was Lando made a general and given such a prominent role in the attack on the Death Star?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

I'm looking for an in-universe reason why Lando was chosen to be the main General leading the attack on the Death Star? I know Akbar was the Admiral but surely the alliance had more experienced and longer serving members?

Is there anything in canon to say Lando had the experience and wherewithal to lead the attack?

Had an answer about the manoeuvre at the battle of taanab, but that's not really what I'm looking for. It's a throw away line that doesn't explain why Lando was made a general above more experience alliance members.

Comment: Because Solo vouched for him and because he's knocking space-boots with  the leader of the rebellion. Leia that is, not Akbar. Eww.

Comment: I thought mon mothma was de-facto leader of the rebellion?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that Han Solo wasn't sleeping with them either.

Comment: I guess no one told you about his little manouver at the battle of Taneb...

Comment: It's just bad writing (again). Generals do strategy, not tactics. Also remember that they made Jar Jar a general too.

Comment: @Gaius that's why I love this site, I didn't know there was a difference between tactics and strategy. Learn something every day!

Comment: Aren't generals for ground forces? Or are the fighter wing, which the Falcon was assigned, considered an "air force" of some sort?

Comment: Is there a reason my answer wasn't accepted? It covered the ground in far mroe detail than the currently accepted one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Han Solo: Well, look at you! A General, huh?
>   Lando Calrissian: Someone must have told them all about my little maneuver at the battle of Taanab.
>   Han Solo: Well, don't look at me, pal. I just said you were a fair pilot. I didn't know they were looking for somebody to *lead* this crazy attack.
>   Lando Calrissian: I'm surprised they didn't ask you to do it.
>   Han Solo: Well, who says they didn't? Only I ain't crazy.

Comment: It might also be a remnant of his history in the Clone Wars in earlier scripts. Landfill was supposed to have been one of the clones.

Comment: Is there anything further that explains what the manoeuvre was that justifies an immediate commission of general? Or was the alliance that short on leaders?

Comment: General is not just a rank, it is a job description. Lando is not seen doing the work of a General, he is flying a ship like a Lieutenant.

Comment: @Gaius he orders other wings about doesn't he? More like a squadron leader then?

Comment: It was a disorganized rebellion. They're always short of qualified leadership, so anyone who shows signs of being able to lead a Gungan to water can get a command.

Comment: @Carl yep, but certainly not a General -whereas Akbar is seen doing the work of an Admiral.

Comment: the weirdest thing is hes given the title general, when typically general is not used in navel battles, nor their equivalent, space battles, it is usually a ground force leader title. Especially since we already have admiral akbar, as the imperial fleet i believe have admirals as well.

Comment: @Himarm Consider the X-Wing, Y-Wing etc. as airforce, and airforce has the same ranks as army, not navy. IIRC in WWII American fighter squadrons were usually lead by a Major, sometimes by a Lt.Colonel. The CAG of a carrier was a Navy Captain or a Marine Corps Colonel. In ROTJ Lando is leading the whole fighter strike force, consisting of many squadrons, so Colonel would have been the *minimum* rank for that.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there anything in canon to say Lando had the experience and wherewithal to lead the attack?

Yes.

James Kahn's novelization of ROTJ covers details of that:

> Lando laughed affectionately. “I’m a man of many faces and many costumes. Someone must have told them about my little maneuver at the battle of Taanab.” **Taanab was an agrarian planet raided seasonally by bandits from Norulac. Calrissian—before his stint as governor of Cloud City—had wiped out the bandits against all odds, using legendary flying and unheard of strategies**. And he’d done it on a bet.

Lando was also an experienced pilot, as we see in Han Solo trilogy, he actually owned Millenium Falcon before Han did. **Just what you want in someone leading a fighter assault spearheaded by Millenium Falcon**.